# NSMenu didnt adopt appearance VibrantDark style

Tags: xcode, macos, nsmenu, appearance

In my app I have an NSMenu, it works fine except it has the wrong appearance. The application has a VibrantDark style, all buttons and popupButtons show correctly in this style.

But when I create NSMenu it shows it as the light style. NSMenu does not have an appearance property. I tried to create my own custom menu, but it didn't draw out of the frame borders. Why doesn't NSMenu adopt the appearance?

Comment: Please do post your code so that someone can help you.

Comment: I have this problem too - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, correct code:
mouseMenu.popUp(positioning: pointMenu.item(at: 0),
                        at: NSEvent.mouseLocation(),
                        in: self)